# Repeat entry in data.frame filled from for() loop

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

I have a data set containing observations for individuals and years.  I want to isolate the data to each individual.  Within each individual, I want to fit a number of models for each year. I then want to compile the AIC score for each individual-year model into a `data.frame`, which are then held in a list.

I have created a reproducible example below using the `iris` data.  I am using a nested for loop to subset the data to individual (i) and then year (j).

**Problem**:  Some species have data for three years (e.g. setosa and versicolor), while virginica only has data for a single year (2014).

When the species `data.frames` are added to the list, species with fewer than three years contain repeat records from the previous years.  As seen in the results below, `list[[3]]` should contain a single row of data for the virginica species in 2014 and not also the repeat records of versicolor from 2011 and 2012.

Is it possible to have a list of `data.frames` with different number of rows?

I welcome any suggestions to improve the nested for loop.  I suspect there are better ways to do this, maybe with `dplyr`

```
head(iris)

#Add year to iris to reproduce problem
iris$Year <- c(rep(c("2011", "2012", "2013"), len = 100), rep("2014", 50))

#Make list of species of index and empty list
Sp <- unique(iris$Species)
ResultsList <- list()

#make Results table
AICTbl <- data.frame(Species = as.character(), AIC_1 = numeric(), AIC_2 = numeric(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

#run nested for loop
for(i in 1:length(Sp)) {
  SpeciesDat <- subset(iris, Species == Sp[i])

  for(j in 1:length(unique(SpeciesDat$Year))) {
    Years <- unique(SpeciesDat$Year)
    datasub <- SpeciesDat[SpeciesDat$Year == Years[j] , ]

    #Make the animal Year rowID
    AICTbl[j,1] = paste(Sp[i] , Years[j], sep = "_")

    mod.1 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = datasub)
    AICTbl[j,2] = AIC(mod.1)

    mod.2 <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = datasub)
    AICTbl[j,3] = AIC(mod.2)

          }
        ResultsList[[i]] <- AICTbl
    }


> ResultsList
[[1]]
      Species    AIC_1     AIC_2
1 setosa_2011 3.649775 21.089619
2 setosa_2012 4.512392  2.280987
3 setosa_2013 4.638183 19.718576

[[2]]
          Species    AIC_1    AIC_2
1 versicolor_2013 25.30007 18.93356
2 versicolor_2011 26.57170 15.22717
3 versicolor_2012 21.62511 11.82291

[[3]]
          Species    AIC_1    AIC_2
1  virginica_2014 89.88263 32.91367
2 versicolor_2011 26.57170 15.22717
3 versicolor_2012 21.62511 11.82291
```

**Addition**
Thanks for your suggestions and improvements @jeremycg.  The following addition is a continuation, although you have answered the OP.  Any additional thoughts would be appreciated.

A non-reproducible example of my real code is included below which shows one of 5 models that are fitted for each IndID-Year.

```
datasub %>% group_by(IndID, Year) %>% 
    do(m.1 = try(nls(NSD ~ (asym/(1+exp((t1 - J_day_new)/dur1)))+(-asym/(1+exp((t2 - J_day_new)/dur2))), 
          control=nls.control(maxiter = 1000, warnOnly=TRUE), algorithm="port",
                  start=c(asym=0.75*max(datasub$NSD), t1=135, t2=285, dur1=2, dur2=2),
              data = datasub),TRUE)

      ) %>%
    mutate(m.1 = AIC(m.1))
```

If I replace `datasub` (the data frame) with `.` I get the following error.

```
Error in UseMethod("logLik") : 
  no applicable method for 'logLik' applied to an object of class "try-error"
```

Comment: To split a data frame by two variables use `split(dataset, dataset[ , c('var1', 'var1')])`.It will make your code short. And of course a list can have data frame with different number of rows. A list is a generic vector. Example: `df1 <- data.frame(1:3, 4:6); df2 <- data.frame(1:5, 6:10); l1 <- list(df1, df2)`. It works in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a pretty convoluted code here. We can simplify it out using `dplyr`. If you are doing a lot of modelling by groups, you might also want to check out the `broom` package.

Here's a shorter version of your code:

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% group_by(Species, Year) %>%
         do(mod1 = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .),
            mod2 = lm(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length, data = .)) %>%
         mutate(mod1 = AIC(mod1), mod2 = AIC(mod2))

Source: local data frame [7 x 4]
Groups: <by row>

     Species  Year      mod1      mod2
      (fctr) (chr)     (dbl)     (dbl)
1     setosa  2011  3.649775 21.089619
2     setosa  2012  4.512392  2.280987
3     setosa  2013  4.638183 19.718576
4 versicolor  2011 26.571702 15.227167
5 versicolor  2012 21.625111 11.822912
6 versicolor  2013 25.300073 18.933559
7  virginica  2014 89.882627 32.913666
```

If you really do want it in a list, you can assign the above output to `z`, then split by species:

```
split(z, list(z$Species))
```

Comment: Thanks.  Very helpful.  I have been reading up on "." but wonder if you could also provide additional info.  Using 'data = iris' will result in the same answer for each Species-Year.  As far as I can tell, the "." is used to call the data that has been grouped with group_by.  I am getting an error when I apply your code to my real problem, which uses the nls function. Replacing my data frame with "." produces the error further described in the OP.

Comment: it looks like some of your `nls` calls are failing, and the `AIC` is being called on the error message from `try`.  You could try replacing the AIC(m.1) with: `ifelse(class(m.1) == "try-error", NA, AIC(m.1))`. Yes you are correct about the dots - after a `%>%` the preceding stuff is used as the first argument to the next function. If you want it somewhere else (ie `data = .`) you need to use a dot to signify this. Also check out the [broom + dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/vignettes/broom_and_dplyr.html) - it will help you down the line